# How to find and kill running Processes from within Java?

Tags: java, kill, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I need a Java way to find a running OS process from which I know to name and path of the executable. I want to look whether it is running right now and I need a way to kill the process if I found it.

My Question is a similar to [how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902/how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java) but not restricted to windows.

Am I forced to do an implementation per platform or is there some trick/library/api I'm missing that can do this?

Comment: Theres no platform independent way of doing this afaik.

Comment: There seem to be some libraries mentioned here that might do what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192081/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-unix-process-from-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home#Home-license) library has some pretty cool support for stuff like this.  It has java APIs for listing and killing system processes.

Comment: Havnt had time to test it yet, but looks what im after